# Bus error: 10 when multiplying two matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

When performing the multiplication of two matrices (`matmul`) in Numpy the program quits with the error Bus error: 10. No other error messages are presented.

The error occurs when performing the multiplication of two matrices.

```
out = w_col @ x_col
```

`w_col` is the matrix of shape `(64, 27)` and with type `float32`.
`x_col` is the matrix of shape `(27, 12996)` and with type `float32`.

The error happens with any Numpy 10.15.* and Numpy 10.16.* on MacOS 10.14.3

Is that possible that issue is caused by large input matrices?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a bus error in Python at all – it means there's a low-level error with an extension accessing memory it shouldn't. How have you installed Numpy? (For what it's worth, I can't reproduce this on my NumPy 1.16.1.)

Comment: I think the reason is that some Numpy operations are partly implemented in C.Numpy is installed via `pip`. It is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: I can not reproduce the same error with the simple script even if I am using the same data. It seems that the reason for crash must be the cascade of more operations. I will try to prepare the example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Okay. You could also try just rebooting your machine – could be a transient fault of some sort :)

Comment: It seems that it is not only a problem with my machine. I got the same error at the other machine.

Comment: Okay. Looking forward to seeing the minimal reproducible example – this could well be a bona fide NumPy bug.